# How to achieve distributed transaction in spring batch processing

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

Suppose,
I have 2 databases (e.g: db1, db2) and i want to insert db1 (tbl_customer), db2(tbl_order) after ItemProcess. I mean while call Iteam writter from step. I already, create multidata source for that case but i need some help about distribute inseration with different database different table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a composite item writer with two delegates (one writer per database) and two transaction managers (one per database).

Now in order to correctly maintain the transaction status between both business databases and the one you use for Batch meta-data, you need to configure the step with a `JtaTransactionManager` (with the two transaction managers as delegates) to coordinate the distributed transaction.